# android Listview:How to stop the header scroll?

Tags: android, listview, header

I make a listview in android, i use list.addHeadView() add a header. and the header has two imageviews, vertical. I want to do this:when scroll the listview until the first imageview out if sight, and then the second imageview stop scroll at the place.thanks